# MVVM approach with VSTO and Excel. Use Excel as View part of MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, vsto

I have spent the last days learning the principles of C# and and MVVM. I am wondering if Excel with VSTO could be used as the View part of an MVVM application.

I am trying to build an excel based tool that interfaces to my Broker, gets stock price updates and helps me to automate order placing (by calculating the right levels, etc.) For that I would like to use excel because many of the calculations can just be done in excel without coding and I can use sheets to log my trades, do statistics etc.

I have looked into the API of my brokers, which comes with a REst API and a Streaming AP (IGMarkets) and a sample WPF application in c#. The UI part is obviously a windows application with some WPF forms and mostly lists, so what I am trying to find out if VSTO supports using Excel as the view part of such applications, where sheets or ranges would be bound to objects in my ViewModels and where I can trigger commands or events when a user changes elements of certain cells or maybe also presses buttons that I could place inside of the sheets.

Is this a usecase of VSTO or am I on the wrong path?

I have looked into VBA accessing Rest, or even using DDE, but C# seems to be more modern and it makes my life easier if I can work in VStudio with Intellisense and everything.

Comment: No, you can't embed excel in a wpf application.  Yes, you can find excel-like controls that offer the same benefits. No, asking for links is off topic.  Yes, you can find them with any search engine. No, we won't tell you which are better. Yes, you can prototype with each and find which suits your needs better.

Comment: I get that , just for clarification, I dont want to use MVVM I was just wondering if there was a kind of similar design pattern if one wants to use excel as kind of the UI where some code in the background updates data visible in the sheets and reacts on user inputs.

Comment: Sounds like an office add-in

Comment: I know that for Word, VSTO doesn't provide a whole lot of events to react to. And, Word can't respond to programming events, only UI events. I think you might run into the same problem with Excel. Check out the MSDN entries for Application, Workbook, and Worksheet events.

Comment: It's a bit late, but there's a GitHub project that may be what you're looking for. It allows you to develop in a MVVM style within Office Add-ins. https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/VSTOContrib/blob/master/README.md